# unity press a key constant changing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to use a get key press enter, then it will send the username and password to back end. How can I disable people pressing enter, or make something that can make this, even user press enter, the function doesn't run itself anymore, because it actually already success.

```
public void OnPressConfirmUser()
{
    string username = Username.GetComponent<InputField>().text;
    string password = Password.GetComponent<InputField>().text;
    userRegister.PostUser(username, password);

    if (userRegister.Proceed())
    {
        UserInfoUI.SetActive(false);
    }
}

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return))
    {
        OnPressConfirmUser();
    }
}
```

For the first time, it works, and it goes to another menu that doesn't have these two input field, and now I can still press enter and see something in my debug log. How can I make when first time you press that button, then even you press enter, there is nothing happen?

Comment: how do you want it to not proceed? is it dependent on userRegistered.Proceed() result? if so, your { } brackets are misplaced

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a bool flag to detect if the player pressed button and only change its value after backend returns true?

Something like:

```
private bool tryingLogin; //property in the script

void Update(){

    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Return) && !tryingLogin) {
        tryingLogin = true;
        OnPressConfirmUser ();
    }
}
```

Then when your backend returns true/false, you can set tryingLogin to false again.
You can also have a object to manage login, so you don't have to call that function every time.